# Why do we need to go for JQuery?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Newbie to JQuery ..

Why do we need to go for Jquery ? Or, What difference it makes on bringing JQuery instead of AJAX / Javascript ?
Whether JQuery is the replacement of AJAX and Javascript ?

Comment: I think it's a little argumentative, but in general - it's the whole "do we want to reinvent things that already do what we want to do and is well-tested and maintained by a large community, or do we want to reinvent it in-house and let it obstruct new exploration that we have to do?" If jQuery does stuff you need, it's probably a better base to start with.

Comment: @birryree The OP does not understand the difference between jQuery and JavaScript. His question is not: Should I use jQuery or not?, but: What's the difference between jQuery and JavaScript?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - yeah, guess I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: I don't understand why are many people down voting? user620720 just doesn't know jQuery (and maybe doesn't know javascript good enough).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is the library written on javascript.

Pros:

1. you don't have to reimplement
   basic DOM and so on operations;
2. all functions are guaranteed to
   work in all supported (by jQuery)
   browsers;
3. it uses most new features of new
   browsers (if possible);
4. your traffic is only reduced if
   you write huge environment using
   jQuery.

jQuery doesn't replace any javascript functionality of course. And it adds lots of useful lightweight utilities.

Comment: Thank you , Do you have something to say about CONS ..!

Comment: @user620720 - Cons: Each new version weights more than previous :) I am using 1.3.2 because 1.5 is a few times bigger and I don't use new functionality (but it's only my choise).

Comment: jQuery 1.5 is 29kB (minified and gzipped)... unacceptable! `:)`

Comment: @Šime Vidas - But not all (most but not all) browsers accept compression of HTTP traffic. Maybe you are right `:)` Now it is not important, I must change my opinion on this point.

Answer (score 11):

**JavaScript** = a programming language

**AJAX** = a method of retrieving resources asynchronously via HTTP using JavaScript

**jQuery** = a library (collection of functions, etc.) written in JavaScript

Answer (score 4):

jQuery isn't a "replacement" for javascript, or AJAX. It's just a wrapper or library for javascript to make things like AJAX easier to setup and get working across browsers.

Comment: I am not arguing .. ! But i have a feeling that .. AJAX and Javascript does the same ..! Javascript is a Traditional client side scripting ..!

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery, but like any library it speeds up development. If I was developing a numerical weather code I would want to use library functions that calculate trigonometric functions like SIN, COS, TAN etc and a Fast-Fourier-Transform routine wouldn't do amiss either. I could develop them myself and spend a lot of time debugging them, by why should I when there are versions already developed and tested and provided by standard mathematical libraries. So it is with jQuery, which as Mike points out, is written in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

[Write Less, Do More](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: If i am using JQuery, can i assume that i dont want to use either Ajax or Javascript ..!

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense. jQuery and Ajax do not make for an “either / or” situation.

Comment: @user620720 - jQuery is a Javascript framework.  Ajax is also javascript.  So no, you can't assume that.

Comment: Ajax is not JavaScript, it is something you can do with JavaScript. (Ajax is to JavaScript as "Driving into town" is to "a vehicle")

Comment: @David - "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML" - and my point was they all use javascript, they're definitely not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a library (like YUI, Mootools, Prototype.js and a host of others). It doesn't replace JavaScript or Ajax, it just provides some prewritten JavaScript functions (some of which perform Ajax operations) so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you .., and I believe this website : stackoverflow is mainly driven on JQuery ..!